# Order by dimension mdx

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-2012

I have this MDX:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[InventarioSobreVentas] AS [Measures].[InventarioDirecto_Monto]/[Measures].[VentasInventarioDirecto_Ventas]*100 SELECT NON EMPTY {
 [Measures].[InventarioDirecto_Monto], 
[Measures].[VentasInventarioDirecto_Ventas], [Measures].[InventarioSobreVentas] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { (

[Dim_Tiempo_].[Anio].[Anio].ALLMEMBERS 
*[Dim_Tiempo_].[NombreMesAbreviado].[NombreMesAbreviado].ALLMEMBERS
* [Dim_Tiempo_].[Mes].[Mes].ALLMEMBERS
* [Dim_Tiempo_].[Dim_Tiempo_].[Dim_Tiempo_].ALLMEMBERS
* [Dim_PlantaConsolidada_].[Grupo].[Grupo].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_PlantaConsolidada_].[IdGrupo].[IdGrupo].ALLMEMBERS
 * [Dim_PlantaConsolidada_].[Unidad].[Unidad].ALLMEMBERS
 * [Dim_PlantaConsolidada_].[IdUnidad].[IdUnidad].ALLMEMBERS
 * [Dim_PlantaConsolidada_].[sNombrePlantaConsolidada].[sNombrePlantaConsolidada].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_PlantaConsolidada_].[keyIdPlantaConsolidada].[keyIdPlantaConsolidada].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Dim_ConceptosInventario_].[Dim_ConceptosInventario_].[Dim_ConceptosInventario_]
 )}
 DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_VALUE, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
--FROM ( SELECT ( {[Dim_PlantaConsolidada_].[keyIdPlantaConsolidada].[All] } ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DimPlantaConsolidadaSNombrePlanta, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 

FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DimPlantaConsolidadaIdUnidad, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
 FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DimTiempoAnio, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM [BSC]
)))
--))) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

As you can see I have column called:

```
* [Dim_Tiempo_].[Mes].[Mes].ALLMEMBERS
```

and result come as:
[image]

Values 1 to 12, problem is I need to order it ascending like, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 but mdx is so complicated, I try to use `ORDER` filter but I always get error. Is not possible to order by Dimension?

Answer (score 0):

You can put ORDER around all the rows set:

```
...
NON EMPTY 
ORDER( 
     [Dim_Tiempo_].[Anio].[Anio].ALLMEMBERS 
    *[Dim_Tiempo_].[NombreMesAbreviado].[NombreMesAbreviado].ALLMEMBERS
    *[Dim_Tiempo_].[Mes].[Mes].ALLMEMBERS
    *[Dim_Tiempo_].[Dim_Tiempo_].[Dim_Tiempo_].ALLMEMBERS
    *[Dim_PlantaConsolidada_].[Grupo].[Grupo].ALLMEMBERS 
    *[Dim_PlantaConsolidada_].[IdGrupo].[IdGrupo].ALLMEMBERS
    *[Dim_PlantaConsolidada_].[Unidad].[Unidad].ALLMEMBERS
    *[Dim_PlantaConsolidada_].[IdUnidad].[IdUnidad].ALLMEMBERS
    *[Dim_PlantaConsolidada_].[sNombrePlantaConsolidada].[sNombrePlantaConsolidada].ALLMEMBERS 
    *[Dim_PlantaConsolidada_].[keyIdPlantaConsolidada].[keyIdPlantaConsolidada].ALLMEMBERS 
    *[Dim_ConceptosInventario_].[Dim_ConceptosInventario_].[Dim_ConceptosInventario_]
  ,[Dim_Tiempo_].[Mes].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION //<<OR [Dim_Tiempo_].[Mes].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE
  ,BASC
)  
ON ROWS 
...
```